# Javascript forms/ not working in every case

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried to build a  validation form using JavaScript which handles these errors:

1. The Name field should not be empty
2. The phone number field can contain only numbers (exactly 10 numbers)
3. One option should be selected (radio)
4. At least one car from checkboxes is selected and at max 3 cars

But the problem with my code is it has not worked in all cases. I mean if I selected submit it shows me the error message just in the name field, not on other fields.

For example here -

[image]

here my HTML code

```
<body>
<div class="MainBackground">
    <h1 id="title">Car Company</h1>
</div>
<div class="cars">
    <form method="POST" name="form-car" id="form-car">
        <p id="decription"> users' request</p>
        <div id="name_div">
            <label id="lable-name" for="name">Name: </label>
            <input id="name" type="text" name="yourName" placeholder="Enter your name"> <br>
            <span id="errorname"></span>
        </div>
        <br> <br>
        <label id="lable-Phone" for="Phone">Phone:</label>
        <input id="phone" type="text" name="phonefild" placeholder="Enter your Phone Number"> <br>
        <span id="errorpass"></span>
        <br> <br>
        <label id="lable-age" for="Age">Age:</label>
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="group1" value="T"> 18-25
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="group1" value="A"> 26-35
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="group1" value="O"> 35-55
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="group1" value="AO"> 36-80
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="group1" value="VO"> 80-95
        <br>
        <span id="radioerorr"></span>
        <br> <br>
        <label for="check">Choice cars to tested</label>
        <br>
        <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="option1" name="car1" value="BMW">
        <label for="vehicle1">BMW</label><br>
        <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="option2" name="car2" value="Ferrari">
        <label for="vehicle2">Ferrari</label><br>
        <input checkbox="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="option3" name="car3" value="Ford">
        <label for="vehicle3">Ford</label><br>
        <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="option4" name="car4" value="Audi">
        <label for="vehicle4">Audi</label><br>
        <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="option5" name="car5" value="Cadillac">
        <label for="vehicle5">Cadillac</label><br>
        <span id="checkboxerorr"></span>
        <br> <br>
        <div class="center">
            <button onclick="return validition()" id="submit" type="submit" name="button">submit</button>
            <button id="reset" type="reset" name="button">reset</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

And here my javascript code

```js
function validition() {

    var phoneinpute = document.getElementById('phone').value;
    var radios = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    var value;
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    var count1 = 0;
    var count2 = 0;
    var regex = /(5|0)([0-9]{8})$/;


    if (document.getElementById('name').value == "") {
        document.getElementById('errorname').innerHTML = "name should not be empty";
        document.getElementById('name').style.borderColor = "red";
        return false;
    } else if (document.getElementById('name').value != "") {
        document.getElementById('errorname').innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById('name').style.borderColor = "green";

    }
    if (regex.test(phoneinpute)) {
        document.getElementById('errorpass').innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById('phone').style.borderColor = "green";

        //return true;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('errorpass').innerHTML = "Invalide phone number";
        document.getElementById('phone').style.borderColor = "red";
        return false;
    }


    for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
        if (radios[i].type == "radio" && radios[i].checked) {
            count1++;
        }

        if (count1 == 1) {
            document.getElementById('radioerorr').innerHTML = "";
            break;

        } else {
            document.getElementById('radioerorr').innerHTML = "one option should be selected";
            return false
        }


    }





    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        if (inputs[i].type == "checkbox" && inputs[i].checked) {
            count2++;
        }

        if (count2 > 3 || count2 == 0) {
            document.getElementById('checkboxerorr').innerHTML = "please choose at least one car and at most 3 cars";
            return false
        } else {
            document.getElementById('checkboxerorr').innerHTML = "";
        }
    }
```

Comment: sorry for the spelling and the grammar  * my code does not work in all cases

Comment: Is this really a php question?

Comment: no, but I tried to bring the php programmer here lol

Comment: @XAN What is wrong with the answer I provided you below? The `javascript` I provided will do everything you asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `return` statements in your validations, if you return from your 1st validation (name box), the other code blocks will not execute. Use a local `boolean` to determine your `return` type and `return` that at the end of your `function`, that way, all of your validation code runs. Also, your radio button and checkbox validation logic is flawed, you set an error message on each iteration of the loop if count1 or count2 doesn't meet your conditions. Change it to something like the following:

```
function validition() {
        let valid = true; //local boolean to return at the end of your function
        var phoneinpute = document.getElementById('phone').value;
        var radios = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
        var value;
        var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
        var count1 = 0;
        var count2 = 0;
        var regex = /(5|0)([0-9]{8})$/;

        //Name validation
        if (document.getElementById('name').value == "") {
            document.getElementById('errorname').innerHTML = "name should not be empty";
            document.getElementById('name').style.borderColor = "red";
            valid = false;
        } else if (document.getElementById('name').value != "") {
            document.getElementById('errorname').innerHTML = "";
            document.getElementById('name').style.borderColor = "green";

        }
        //Phone number validation
        if (regex.test(phoneinpute)) {
            document.getElementById('errorpass').innerHTML = "";
            document.getElementById('phone').style.borderColor = "green";
        } else {
            document.getElementById('errorpass').innerHTML = "Invalide phone number";
            document.getElementById('phone').style.borderColor = "red";
            valid = false;
        }

        //Radio button validation
        for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
            if (radios[i].type == "radio" && radios[i].checked) {
                count1++;
            }

            if (count1 == 1) {
                document.getElementById('radioerorr').innerHTML = "";
                break;    
            } 
        }
        
        //check to see if you had a checked radio button, if not, add error
        //and mark local boolean as false
        if(count1 < 1){
           document.getElementById('radioerorr').innerHTML = "one option should be selected";
           valid = false;
        }

        //Checkbox validation
        for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
            if (inputs[i].type == "checkbox" && inputs[i].checked) {
                count2++;
            }
        }

        //Do your checkbox validation after the for loop
        if (count2 > 3 || count2 == 0) {
            document.getElementById('checkboxerorr').innerHTML = "please choose at least one car and at most 3 cars";
            valid = false;
         } else {
            document.getElementById('checkboxerorr').innerHTML = "";
         }

        //return your local boolean value
        return valid;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much it works now, but except for the checkbox validation it gives me an errors message even if I choose more than 3 options

Comment: @XAN Please see my most recent edit, I had to fix the logic on that as well.

Comment: @XAN You could also improve this, by using the same collection on your `for` loops, you are setting two different variables to the same collection of `inputs`, you could just iterate the same collection.

Comment: thank you, I tried your update but instead of fixing the checkbox error the whole form does not give any error message. For example, name is empty it does not show the red message

Comment: @XAN I left a `break` statement in the checkbox validation`if` statement near the end, oops, it was probably causing a syntax error, please see new `edit`

Comment: @XAN It's supposed to give you an error message if you check more than 3. Look at your logic. `if (count2 > 3 || count2 == 0) {`

Comment: @XAN You're logic says, if more than 3 checkboxes are checked or zero checkboxes are checked, set the error message.